# Counting the average of duplicates per id in R

Tags: r, data-science

My data looks like this:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 1 | c |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | z |
| 2 | z |
| 2 | e |
| 2 | x |

I want to calculate the average of duplicates per id i.e for id=1 we have 2a 1b 3c I want the output to be 2.
The result shoulbe like this:

| id | mean |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1.333 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
# dt <- your_data_frame %>% as.data.table()  ## convert to table from frame
dt[, .(N=.N), by = .(id,date)][, .(mean = mean(N)), by = id]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mean(table(date))` to get average of counts, apply it by for each `id` value.

Using dplyr -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(table(date)))

#     id  mean
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1  2   
#2     2  1.33
```

Or with base R `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(date~id, df, function(x) mean(table(x)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  count(date) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(n))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id  mean
  <int> <dbl>
1     1  2   
2     2  1.33
```

Using base `R` you can try

```
foo <- function(x) mean(rle(x)$length)
aggregate(d$date, by=list(d$id), foo)
```

The data

```
d <- read.table(text ="id   date
1     a
1     a
1     b
1     c
1     c
1     c
2     a
2     a
2     e
2     z", header=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .(Mean = .N / uniqueN(date)), id]
   id     Mean
1:  1 2.000000
2:  2 1.333333
```

or

```
dcast(setDT(df), id ~ date, fill = NA)[, .(Mean = rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE)), id]
```

gives

```
   id     Mean
1:  1 2.000000
2:  2 1.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     summarise(Mean = count(cur_data(), date) %>% 
              pull(n) %>%
               mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `table` approach using the `base` package:

```
at<-table(a$id,a$date)
apply(at,1,function(x) sum(x)/sum(x!=0))

#       1        2 
#2.000000 1.333333
```

The dataset:

```
a = data.frame('id'=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),'date'=c('a','a','b','c','c','c','a','a','e','z'))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a package free solution

```
a = cbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),c('a','a','b','c','c','c','a','a','e','z'))
b = matrix(ncol = 2)[-1,]
for(i in unique(a[,1])){
  
  b=rbind(b,c(i,sum(table(a[a[,1]==i,2]))/length(table(a[a[,1]==i,2]))))
}
```

The output:

```
    [,1] [,2]              
[1,] "1"  "2"               
[2,] "2"  "1.33333333333333"
```

Comment: this is good but should use `data.frame()` rather than `rbind()` to avoid coercion ...