# In R, what's the average number of repeated column values per ID?

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

**Background**

I've got this `R` dataframe, `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b"),
                event = c("G12","G12","G12","B4","B4","A24","L5","L5"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It looks like this:

[image: d]

As you can see, it's got 2 distinct `ID`'s in it, with each one having `events`, some of which repeat / are duplicated any number of times.

**The Problem**

I'd like to figure out what the average number of repeated `event` is per `ID` in this dataframe.

At a glance, you see that `id`= *a* has **2** events that repeat -- G12, which repeats twice (with 3 entries total) and B4, which repeats once (with 2 total entries). `id`= *b* has **1** event that repeats: L5. Note that how many times each repeat/duplicate occurs is irrelevant to me here; it just matters that there's at least one duplicate `event` per `ID`.

So the result I want is a simple tabulation of that mean:

(**2** events that repeat + **1** event that repeats) / 2 people = **1.5**

**What I've tried**

I've gotten kinda close thanks to posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588263/counting-the-average-of-duplicates-per-id-in-r), but I'm not quite there:

```
d %>% summarise(mean = mean(duplicated(event)))
```

This runs, but it doesn't factor in the fact that the duplication is occurring within `ID` (or at least, that's the way I see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
d %>%
  group_by(event , ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
  summarise(result = mean(n))

  result
1    1.5
```

for `d`

```
  ID event
1   Bill     1
2   Bill     1
3   Bill     2
4   Bill     2
5   Bill     3
6   Bill     3
7   Bill     4
8   Bill     4
9  Sarah     1
10 Sarah     1
11 Sarah     2
12 Sarah     2
13 Sarah     3
14 Sarah     3
15 Sarah     4
16 Sarah     4
17 Sarah     5
18 Sarah     5
19  Jane     1
20  Jane     1

    result
1 3.333333
```

little checkup for code

```
d %>%
  group_by(event , ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = n())

  ID        n
  <chr> <int>
1 Bill      4
2 Jane      1
3 Sarah     5
```

Comment: No, not quite. I need one number that averages the count of repeated `event`s per person in the dataset. So for instnace, imagine that Bill has 4 events that repeat, Sarah has 5 events that repeat, and Jane has 1 event that repeats. (4+5+1) / 3 people == 3.33

Comment: @logjammin Oh...Then in your case, in (2+1)/2, 2 is # of repeated event for a and 1 is # of repeated event for b. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: @logjammin I edit my code above. Thanks for kind explanations.

Comment: Yes that looks great, thanks Park. (Though you don't need to include the Bill / Sarah / Jane parts from my comment, if you don't want -- that was a separate example! )

Answer (score 1):

For each `ID` you may count the `event` which occur more than once and then take the ratio.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(dup = sum(table(event) > 1)) %>%
  summarise(ratio = mean(dup))

#  ratio
#  <dbl>
#1   1.5
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. Question: what if I wanted to group this by a year variable `year`, so that there would be a ratio for each year instead of 1 ratio for the whole dataframe? If it's too much, don't worry at all, I can post as a new question.

Comment: If you change `group_by(ID)` to `group_by(year, ID)` I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

We may do this easily in `base R`

```
mean(rowSums(table(d) > 1))
[1] 1.5
```

---

or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   count(event, ID) %>%
   summarise(ratio = mean(rowsum(+(n> 1), ID)))
  ratio
1   1.5
```